# How to debug on the iPhone itself without xcode? UISearchBar/DisplayController crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a problem: I am programming an app that is using a searchBar and a tableView.

When I click the search bar, type some string to search for, as soon as I hit the cancel button, or delete all the search terms and click the tableView again my app crashes.

When I run the app in the iOS Simulator, it doesn't crash when doing this.

When I run the app on my iPhone via xcode, it doesn't crash when doing this.

I don't really understand the device log and I wanted to ask if there is any way to find out what's going terribly wrong and why this is not happening when doing it via xcode. Please help me!

PS: One of the device logs: (Maybe you guys understand this)

[image: something went wrong]

EDIT: Here's the code of the searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
{    
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"DeactivateSearch" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [self.attractionsTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 43, 320, 362)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[self fetchedResultsController] fetchRequest];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }  

    [self setSearchIsActive:NO];

    return;
}
```

UPDATE: The search bar does NOT crash if no text was typed. So simply activating the searchBar and deactivating it without typing works. But as soon as I have typed a single character the deactivating process crashes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself..

In one of my custom cells I released something too often and thus the app crashed when the UISearchDisplayController was releasing the UITableView for the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an animation callback issue.  Also there is a console log, look at it.

Comment: Log is available in the organizer.  As for your code, you wrote it so really think it through. Call backs with blocks may outlive their caller requiring copying them to the heap.

Comment: I'm really fairly new to objective-C so I don't understand what an animation callback is. I'll edit my question and add the searchDisplaycontrollerDidEndSearch function in there, maybe you can see what the problem is.

Comment: I think it's the deletion of the tableView from the SearchDisplayController that causes the problem, but I don't know why and for what reason :/